# c# routing, asp.net mvc. It is not accepting parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

This is my controller :

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{
    public class HelloWorldController : Controller
    {
        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/ 
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/Welcome/ 
        public string Welcome(string name)
        {
            return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Hello " + name + ", NumTimes is: 55 " );
        }
    }
}
```

This is my route :

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But whenever i pass the url : http://localhost:61114/helloworld/welcome/scott

My output is : Hello , NumTimes is: 55
instead of Hello Scott, NumTimes is: 55

Comment: because your route is `id` - not `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your parameter name should be id

or

your route should be {name} and name = UrlParameter.Optional